# How can I define the size of the drawables in the style file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, dry, android-drawable

I would like to specify just once in **res/values/styles.xml** the size of two checkboxes and their four shape drawables

1. **res/drawable/cb1_checked.xml**
2. **res/drawable/cb1_unchecked.xml**
3. **res/drawable/cb2_checked.xml**
4. **res/drawable/cb2_unchecked.xml**.

This way the size would appear one time in the style rather than four in the drawables.

Neither of the two attempts below work. Can you suggest a solution? (If you see what's wrong with these two attempts, please do mention it.)

----------------------------------------------------------------**Attempt 1**----------------------------------------------------------------

Replace

**res/drawable/cb1_checked.xml**

```
<size android:width="24dp"
      android:height="24dp" />
```

with

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:layout_width">24dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">24dp</item>
```

----------------------------------------------------------------**Attempt 2**----------------------------------------------------------------

Add

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:background">cb_background</item>
```

and define a background drawable

**res/drawable/cb_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00FF00"/>
    <size android:width="24dp"
          android:height="24dp" />
</shape>
```

----------------------------------------------------------------**Added**----------------------------------------------------------------

Here is the full set of XML files:

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyLL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb1"
        style="@style/CB_style"
        android:button="@drawable/cb1_selector"
        android:height="@dimen/my24sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb2"
        style="@style/CB_style"
        android:button="@drawable/cb2_selector"
        android:height="@dimen/my24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>

<style name="CB_style" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:checked">false</item>
</style>
```

**res/drawable/cb1_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:constantSize="true">

    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/cb1_checked" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/cb1_unchecked" />

</selector>
```

**res/drawable/cb1_checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <size android:width="24dp"
          android:height="24dp" />
</shape>
```

**res/drawable/cb1_unchecked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#880000"/>
    <size android:width="24dp"
          android:height="24dp" />
</shape>
```

(and similarly for the cb2 selector and checked/unchecked drawables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a weak solution, weak in the sense that **android:width** and **android:height** still appear four times, but at least the dimension can be adjusted by setting just one parameter.

For each of the four drawables, add

```
<size android:width="@dimen/my24dp"
      android:height="@dimen/my24dp" />
```

and also define the dimension

**res/values/dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="my24dp">24dp</dimen>
```

So the question remains: Can the size not be specified at all in the drawables?

Comment: I'm doing literally the same thing and this answer works. OP should accept this answer.

Comment: I did the same thing but it isn't work. I have the following error `Error:Error: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0`. I have min skd tarket set to 19.

Comment: @roroinpho21 It sounds simple, but anything one could suggest here would be just a guess. Double-check and post a question.

Answer (score 0):

you could store your size as a ressource in the `res/values/dimens.xml` like

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="checkbox_width">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and put this value to your layouts like

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="@dimen/checkbox_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/checkbox_width" />
```

Comment: really? what's the error?   after you create the new dimens.xml you should clean your project.. than java is creating the reference id to get the value with your @dimen/checkbox_width

Comment: There is no error. Nothing appears in either Eclipse or the device. Could you look at the full set of files that I have now added and see if there is something that makes your solution not work on my side?