# Scale with button press using selector

Tags: java, android, xml

so my selector works all good and well but I want the button to change size when press as well. Is there a way to change the  `android:layout_height` inside the selector?

My current selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="false" >

<item
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/grey_button08"

/>
<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/grey_button09"

/>
</selector>
```

Comment: You can't change the size or padding by xml selector, You can do this by java code on onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697672/4593670) post.
  You can set your background as a shape and set size attrs to it

Comment: probably should have mentioned it's an image button